# -[FBSDKLoginManager logInWithReadPermissions:fromViewController:handler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I've updated to Parse 1.9.1, Facebook SDK v4.x, iOS 9, Swift 2, and Xcode 7. Didn't change any code and added my `.plist` keys for `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` and `App Transport Security Settings`.

Now, I can't log into Facebook using `class func logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions: [String]?, block: PFUserResultBlock?)` because I get this error:

```
2015-10-30 15:24:22.433 [2905:830174] -[FBSDKLoginManager logInWithReadPermissions:fromViewController:handler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15ee75d60
2015-10-30 15:24:22.437 [2905:830174] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FBSDKLoginManager logInWithReadPermissions:fromViewController:handler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15ee75d60'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x182f60f48 0x197b13f80 0x182f67c5c 0x182f64c00 0x182e68cac 0x1003de54c 0x1003dd36c 0x1003dd1f0 0x10024d8dc 0x100253578 0x100253de0 0x1002f8864 0x1002fc8cc 0x1002fc618 0x1002f9504 0x1002fdc68 0x1002ad868 0x10013ade0 0x10013af50 0x1887a2f24 0x1887a2994 0x1887aaedc 0x1887b10c0 0x1887b04c4 0x18879af14 0x18879ab9c 0x18cd7f7c4 0x18cd7fb44 0x182f18544 0x182f17fd8 0x182f15cd8 0x182e44ca0 0x18e080088 0x18855cffc 0x10013c8a0 0x1983628b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I'm not using IBuilder so I don't have anything that's not connected in my storyboard, it looks like I'm just missing that `fromViewController` parameter. Facebook briefly mentions it in the changelog, but the method isn't available in the `ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework` and nothing like it exists for use with Parse.

What am I missing here? Why am I getting this exception everytime I log in and how can I fix it?

Comment: I had the same issue today and fixed it by upgrading facebook sdk to the latest 20151026.

Comment: I've tried with 20151026. So I still don't get it.

Comment: Try delete and copy all parse and fb sdk,  instead of replace or merge.

Comment: It looks like your app is still referencing an older version of the SDK. `fromViewController` parameter was added in v4.6.0 so check is your app is referencing anything older. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4.x#4_6_0 You should be able to use `NSLog(@"Fb iOS SDK version: %@", [FBSDKSettings sdkVersion]);` to see the version being referenced.